# pandas: read_csv excluding only certain rows

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import a csv file that looks like this

```
     Irrelevant row
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","Site","Logger","Avg_70mSE_Avg","Avg_60mS_Avg",
"TS","RN","","","metres/second","metres/second",
"","","Smp","Smp","Avg","Avg",
"2010-05-18 12:30:00",0,"Sisters",5068,5.162,4.996
"2010-05-18 12:40:00",1,"Sisters",5068,5.683,5.571
```

The second row is the header but rows 0, 2, 3 are irrelevant. My code at the moment is:

```
parse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=1, index_col=['TIMESTAMP'],
                 parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'], date_parser = parse)
```

The problem is that since rows 2 and 3 don't have correct dates I get an error (or at least I think this the error).

Would it be possible to exclude these rows, using something like `skiprows`, but for rows that are not in the beginning of the file? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `skiprows` keyword to ignore the rows:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv', skiprows=[0, 2, 3], 
             index_col=['TIMESTAMP'], parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'])
```

Which for your sample data gives:

```
                     RECORD     Site  Logger  Avg_70mSE_Avg  Avg_60mS_Avg
TIMESTAMP                                                                
2010-05-18 12:30:00       0  Sisters    5068          5.162         4.996
2010-05-18 12:40:00       1  Sisters    5068          5.683         5.571
```

The first parsed row (`1`) becomes the header and `read_csv`'s default parser correctly parses the timestamp column.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was sure something simple would exist. Will try it when back home.